# Как перенести некоторый текст направо

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста,как перенести некоторый текст направо,при этом оставив другой слева ( .gorod и .nomer ) Как у меня и как нужно снизу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;

}


.navlist  {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

.navlist a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    padding: 1.5em;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.gorod {
    padding: 1.5em;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.gorod, .nomer {
    display: flex;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
         <ul class="navlist" >
            <li><a href="">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Условия возврата</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Отзывы</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
            <li class="gorod">Уфа</li>
            <li class="nomer"><a href="">+7 (762) 283-93-88</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/dyqaQgK - примерно вот так, заводим переменные и ими манипулируем, смотрие возможно будет полезно

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;

}


.navlist  {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.navlist a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    padding: 1.5em;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.gorod {
    padding: 1.5em;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.gorod {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.gorod, .nomer {
    display: flex;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
         <ul class="navlist" >
            <li><a href="">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Условия возврата</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Отзывы</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
            <li class="gorod">Уфа</li>
            <li class="nomer"><a href="">+7 (762) 283-93-88</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]